# I can use print() to get results but storing the result gives me null

Tags: r

I am trying to get the row number in a data set of every time the variable(a serial code) matches a variable (master list of pertinent serial codes) in another data set. 
This is the code that works:

```
for(i in 1:length(y$EIN)){print (which(x$EIN ==y$EIN[i]))}
integer(0)
integer(0)
[1] 14
integer(0)
integer(0)
integer(0)
[1] 15 16 17
integer(0)
integer(0)
integer(0)
(ETC)..
```

When I try to save it like this:

```
 for(i in 1:length(y$EIN)){AP[i]<- (which(x$EIN ==y$EIN[i]))}
```

I just get NAs

I have tried creating another loop just for the new variable. +1 and -1 the index. -1 actually got me to the first result "14" but then stopped running.
I have tried pre-defining the array. I also tried using attach, =, and <-.

Comment: I think you might be better off doing a `merge`.

Comment: I would but I'm not sure how I would get every instance of the serial showing up i.e MasterList( 1, 5, 6 ,8, 9) StockList (2,3,4,5,7,5,5,7,3) I want every 5. The stocklist has the Value data that is important while masterlist only has serial and names.

Comment: What is `AP` in this case? Did you initialize it as a list `AP<-list()`? Then you need to use double brackets to store vectors in lists `AP[[i]] <- ...`